# Method 'getCfg' is deprecated joomla

Tags: joomla4

My phpstorm reports that the following is deprecated:

```
$app      = Factory::getApplication();
$sitename = $app->getCfg('sitename');
```

What is the new correct way to go for this in Joomla 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can fix this using 2 methods,

Method 1:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;  
$app = Factory::getApplication();  
$sitename = $app->getCfg('sitename');
```

Method 2:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();  
$sitename = $app->getCfg('sitename');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
$sitename = $app->get('sitename')
```